# How to get the exact date and time from the valueOf()?

Tags: javascript, date, value-of

we can get the milliseconds from 1970 Jan in js for the current date and time

```
new Date().valueOf()  // 1528191046005
```

form this value (1528191046005) how we can calculate the date and time, is there any way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-utc-t) provides the algorithm, but using the Date constructor is likely easier. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

new Date(your_unix_time * 1000) will result with the required Date object

Comment: The OP doesn't have a "UNIX time", they have a javascript time value and it doesn't need to be multiplied by 1,000 when passed to the Date constructor. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It should just switch back

```
var x=new Date().valueOf();
var y= new Date(x);
console.log(y.toDateString())
```